# can the values of argc and argv passed on to other functions other than the main function?

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist

```
int main(int argc, string argv[ ])
{
    variable(x);
}
```

Such as here. How can I use argv and argc here??

```
int variable(x)
{
    //I want to use argc and argv here..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are just like any other function parameters:

```
int variable(int x, int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 42;
    variable(x, argc, argv);
}
```